# How to export html page into image file in Laravel?

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to make a project to create online greeting card generation. For that purpose I want to convert particular division in view page into image file. How can I render html to image in laravel?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at this 
https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

its done using Canvas2Image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use JS libraries such as [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). To generate an image from the  element you would do [this](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html):

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas); // append image to body
  }
});
```

There are however some limitations (source: official documentation):

> All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same
>   origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a
>   proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which
>   have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty
>   and no longer readable by html2canvas.
>
> The script doesn't render plugin content such as Flash or Java
>   applets. It doesn't render iframe content either.

There are other tools though using command line, such as [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/).